# Reprojecting script runs without errors in Spyder and ArcGIS Pro script tool but desired outcome is not reached

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I am new to Python and am attempting to write a script where the desired spatial reference is found on my `Counties.shp` and the other feature classes are in other projected coordinate systems.

The code runs without failing in Sypder and runs without error as a script tool as well. However, when the script tool is executed the desired outcome is not reached the feature class remains in its original coordinate system.

After some reading, I believe that I need to add `arcpy.Project_management()` using `(fcCurrent,fcOut,targetSr)` for the tool to run but when I try to add it after the `fcOut =` line I get this error:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 160228: The user does not have permission to execute the operation.
> Failed to execute (Project).

````
#establish spatial reference of selected feature class 
targetDesc= arcpy.Describe(targetFc)
targetSr = targetDesc.SpatialReference
targetSrName = targetSr.Name


arcpy.env.workspace = folderWorkspace
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() 

# List current feature classes in folder
for fcCurrent in fcList:
    fcCurrentDesc = arcpy.Describe(fcCurrent)
    fcCurrentSr = fcCurrentDesc.SpatialReference
    fcCurrentSrName = fcCurrentSr.Name 

    
for fcCurrentSrName in fcCurrent: 
    if fcCurrentSrName != targetSrName: 
        print ("Error Matching Spacial reference")
else: 
    print ("Spatial reference matching succesful")

for fcCurrentSrName in fcCurrent:
    if fcCurrentSrName == targetSr:  
        continue
    
else:
    # Output feature class and projected name
    fcOut = os.path.splitext(fcCurrent)[0]
    print (fcOut +"_projected.shp")```
````

Comment: You've got diagnostic print statements; you should include the output  for reference.

Comment: when I run the code it prints: Error Matching Spacial reference (happens 15X for all the feature classes that dont match), Spatial reference matching succesful, StateRoutes_projected.shp

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do. Reproject feature classes to the sr of `targetSr` ?